# What does “Logitem” mean on many freightliners?

Tags: vocabulary, portmanteau-words, clipping

What does *Logitem* mean that I see on the sides of many passing freightliners?

I wonder wether it’s a kind of clipping combining *logistic* with *item*.

I'm not a native speaker but I love English.

Comment: Did you find anything out that you can help us with?

Comment: @Susan http://www.logitem.co.jp/en/service/global.html -- OP is from Vietnam.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - found the same thing, Andrew, and that they were involved in world wide shipping, freight and transport. :( Was asking OP!

Comment: I’m not sure that everyone knows what a *freightliner* means.

Answer (score 7):

*Logitem* is short for ***Logi***stic Sys***tem***s, a company name.  It's formed by taking the first and last two morae of the words as they would be spelled in Japanese and combining them:

> **ロジ**スティック・シス**テム**　*Rojisutikku Shisustemu* = "**Logi**stic Sys**tem**s"
>   **ロジ**　　　　　　　　**テム**　*Rojitemu* = "**Logitem**"

Note that the final *-s* is missing in Japanese.  In Japanese *shisutemu* is used for both *system* and *systems*, which is probably why it's *Logitem* and not *Logitems*.

This sort of abbreviation to four or eight morae is common in Japanese.

If you'd like to see evidence that this is correct, you can see the correspondence between ロジテム (*Rojitemu* = "Logitem") and "Logistic Systems" on their official [Japanese website](http://www.logitem.co.jp/company/outline.html):

> 日本ロジテム株式会社  (*Nihon Rojitemu Kabushikigaisha*)
>   (JAPAN LOGISTIC SYSTEMS CORP.)

Here, *Nihon* means "Japan" and *Kabushikigaisha* is a type of corporation.  You can see plainly that *Rojitemu* corresponds to "Logistic Systems".

It is not an English word and holds no special meaning in English, apart from being short for Logistic Systems.

Answer (score 4):

It first appeared in 1988.

> *Sep 1988* :  Established Logitem Taiwan Co. Ltd. as joint venture between Osaki International Corp. (current Logitem International Corp.) and a customer firm to perform import/export cargo handling, import/export product sales, etc. in Taiwan.
>
> [[Source]](http://www.logitem.co.jp/en/company/outline.html)

[image: Logitem Vietnam lorry]

Logitem is a name, and consequently it may have no meaning at all (except that *Logi-* is fairly obviously related to *logistics* and *item* means "thing"). The company themselves don't appear to explain the name.

<sub>Image from [Japan Logistics Systems Corp](http://www.logitem.co.jp/en/service/global.html)</sub>

Comment: @snailboat Write that as an answer! (However, *item* also works in English.)